# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflite_support.metadata_writers'

Tags: tensorflow, model, metadata, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

```
from tflite_support.metadata_writers import object_detector
from tflite_support.metadata_writers import writer_utils
from tflite_support import metadata

ObjectDetectorWriter = object_detector.MetadataWriter
_MODEL_PATH = "mobile.tflite"
_LABEL_FILE = "labelmap.txt"
_SAVE_TO_PATH = "detect_metadata.tflite"

writer = ObjectDetectorWriter.create_for_inference(
    writer_utils.load_file(_MODEL_PATH), [127.5], [127.5], [_LABEL_FILE])
writer_utils.save_file(writer.populate(), _SAVE_TO_PATH)

# Verify the populated metadata and associated files.
displayer = metadata.MetadataDisplayer.with_model_file(_SAVE_TO_PATH)
print("Metadata populated:")
print(displayer.get_metadata_json())
print("Associated file(s) populated:")
print(displayer.get_packed_associated_file_list())
```

I use this code from link Github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43775

But this code was a bug. Below that is an error after running the above code.

> ---

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-39fd915e7a2a> in <module>()

---->     1 from tflite_support.metadata_writers import object_detector
          2 from tflite_support.metadata_writers import writer_utils
          3 from tflite_support import metadata
          4 
          5 ObjectDetectorWriter = object_detector.MetadataWriter
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflite_support.metadata_writers'

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either `!pip` or `!apt`.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
["Open Examples"](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/importing_libraries.ipynb) button below.

**How to fix this bug?**

Comment: As the note says, did you install the required module?

Answer (score 2):

You must have installed via

```
!pip install tflite_support
```

This is only supported in nightly(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26422) so install via

```
!pip install tflite_support_nightly
```

Answer (score 0):

The tflite_support package on pypi now includes `tflite_support.task`

However, it will not run on Python 3.6. Version 0.3.1 is the latest one that supports Python 3.6. Using Python 3.7 instead of 3.6, and then installing verison 0.4.2 of tflite_support fixed the problem for me.